# How can I manipulate the browser fingerprint?

Tags: browser, privacy

The test here worries me: http://panopticlick.eff.org/ and I'd like to know if there is a good way to manipulate the browser fingerprint?

Comment: Which operating system and which browser?

Answer (score 4):

You can actually do it with a plugin in firefox. It is called Random Agent Spoofer.

> https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/random-agent-spoofer/

This not only takes a random agent, but also changes overtime. And it is also highly customizable.

Does this help you ?

Greets

Comment: This might increase fingerprinting, not reduce it. Relying entirely on the user agent as if it solved the entropy issue that enables fingerprinting is counterproductive. As @pseudon explains in his/her answer, you need a combination of measures to fight fingerprinting. Also note that Panopticlick is not up to date and might return false negatives (saying you are unique while you are not).

Comment: the idea is not increase or decrease but to modify to some other unique fingerprint which is not owned by anyone. Having said that these extensions don't work as they themselves leave traces of spoofing attempt.

Answer (score 3):

It's very difficult to convincingly alter your browser fingerprint without leaving additional fingerprintable traces. The EFF Panopticlick test is a reasonable proof of concept, but there are many other characteristics not tested on that site that can also be used to fingerprint you. Not all fingerprints will use every method, and some will just use a basic fingerprint, so different strategies will have varied effect for different servers. The best defenses are:

Address the highest entropy items first (probably Flash and Java, and the font they reveal, and user agent. User Agent spoofing is difficult to do convincingly. JavaScript is also a key fingerprinting vector (screen size, browser size and position, etc.), turn it off or use something like NoScript.

The Tor browser is also a good defense against device fingerprinting. It has a few built-in protections against fingerprinting.

You're best off choosing a clean, factory-default-configured device (or virtual machine) with a common user agent and other common fingerpritntable characteristics, and using multiple of such devices or VMs to prevent correlation of separate activities.

Answer (score 2):

Suggested answers above are not enough, because changing of User Agent and tricking with plugins doesn't hide your hardware fingerprint.

You can check what browser can get about your hardware using my snippet: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vladignatyev/26219c0975dfe8a4bcdfe4e83d9f12b5/raw/7fdd7c51f58f471dcee987ab6ba7c0e7777f3636/testdevice.js

OS, CPU, RAM, disk storage space, Internet connection and everything else depending on browser. The most "transparent" browser is unfortunately the Google Chrome, he exposes everything listed. Firefox less, but too much also.

Any further ideas/discussion?

Comment: exactly these extensions don't work as they change the values in javascript but while requesting the web it uses different values hence a mismatch makes them easily detectable. I use https://whatleaks.com/ to find out the mismatch

Comment: You missed keybard layout detection for chrome based browsers: `navigator.keyboard.getLayoutMap().then(k => console.log(k.get('KeyQ') + k.get('KeyW') + k.get('KeyE') + k.get('KeyR') + k.get('KeyT') + k.get('KeyY'))) `

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what browser you're using so I'll give you some tips for each.

## Chrome:

- Disable unnecessary plugins aka Flash: chrome://plugins
- Spoof your user agent with this: [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en-US)
- Turn off Do Not Track Requests: chrome://settings
- Disable WebGL: chrome://flags/#disable-webgl

## Firefox:

- Change your user agent to a generic one in: about:config
- Disable HTTP Referrers in: about:config
- Use NoScript: http://noscript.net/

If you need more, clarify which browser you're using and I can add to the list.

Comment: `appVersion` can't be changed by extension

Answer (score 0):

You cant really manipulate the fingerprint by your own.
Its recommend to use various Browsers that set you a completly new Fingerprint.
If you use ***GoLogin*** you have the option to set langauge, spoof hardware like input devices etc.
You also have the option to generate a random unique fingerprint per profile.
You directly can set proxies and spoof the os.
However if you spoof the os then the websites might detect it so if you are on windows keep the os windows, if your on apple keep it on apple and so on.
If you try to completly spoof your fingerprint within a selenium session (sautomate your webbrowser by a program) i recomming you to use python where you can use firefox browser, create custom profiles and set custom options that help to hide your real fingerprint.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This is a paid software. Should be mentioned. https://gologin.com/pricing

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Lalicat antidetect browser** to modify browser fingerprints, such as operating system, time zone, browser version, language, resolution and so on.

Comment: That is insanely expensive though, and it is not clear if it is superior to something like Brave

Comment: Explaining HOW to use this tool to do this would make this an answer. Right now it is merely a comment suggesting a software product but not actually explaining the solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1131655)